# Python + Selenium: Fill the form

Tags: python, parsing, selenium

How can I fill this form https://fedresurs.ru/messages/IsSearching? Input "Message type". Did so earlier:

```
def get_list(n):
    timeout = 3
    try:
        element_present = EC.presence_of_element_located(
            (By.XPATH, '//li[@class="active"]/a/span[text()="{}"]'.format(n)))
        WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(element_present)
    except TimeoutException:
        print("Timed out waiting for page to load")

    lst_divs = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('display-field.message-in-list')
    lst_as = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[starts-with(@id, "ctl00_MainContent_lvMessageList_ctrl")]')
    for d, a in zip(lst_divs, lst_as):
        print('\t{} :: {}'.format(d.text, a.text))

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chromedriver.exe")

url = 'http://fedresurs.ru/messages/IsSearching'

driver.get(url)

driver.find_element_by_id('ctl00_MainContent_sfMessageType_txtObjectName').click()
driver.find_element_by_id('ctl00_MainContent_sfMessageType_txtObjectName').send_keys('Сообщение о выпуске независимой гарантии')

# time.sleep(5)
# s = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_MainContent_btnSearch"]')  # Кнопка поиск
# s.click()
```

now it's not working.

Comment: You may want to read [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Try below code to execute search

```
driver.find_element_by_id('ctl00_MainContent_sfMessageType_txtObjectName').click()
driver.switch_to_frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//iframe[starts-with(@name, "ctl00_radWindowManager")]'))    
driver.find_element_by_id('ctl00_MainContent_tbSearch').send_keys('Сообщение о выпуске независимой гарантии')
driver.find_element_by_id('ctl00_MainContent_btnSearch').click()
```

Comment: I tried that. Nothing is inserted. The field still empty

Comment: try to make click on that field before sending text as in updated answer

Comment: it works, but when pressed Find data is not updated 
mb this value='Сообщение о выпуске независимой гарантии'") is = ID? not text

Comment: Confirm that this https://uploadpie.com/xmopSN is what you want to achieve. If not, clarify your goal

Answer (score 0):

There is one alternative way to send text by executing `javascript`. Try this-

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('ctl00_MainContent_sfMessageType_txtObjectName').value='Сообщение о выпуске независимой гарантии'")
```

Its working at my end for your scenario.

Comment: and so I did, too, the field is filled, but when you click "Find" (Find), the data is not updated for a given category.

Comment: like this s = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_MainContent_btnSearch"]')  # Кнопка поиск
s.click()

Comment: mb this value='Сообщение о выпуске независимой гарантии'") is equal ID?

Comment: No, if open browser console, run document.getElementById('ctl00_MainContent_sfMessageType_txtObjectName').value='Сообщение о выпуске независимой гарантии'", then manual click Find - data is not updating

Comment: Not like that, I mean you just search type or select that string in your site and then click find button , so is it updating the data?

Comment: Yes, is updating data